# How much space does each world take up?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have minecraft PE running on an ipad3 with 64 GB memory.  When I sync with itunes I notice that the apps are now taking up about 20GB of memory.  I have recently added some other apps but think that adding extra worlds in minecraft might be responsible.
Roughly how much space should a world take up from the stored memory on my ipad?

Answer (score 4):

The space is takes up in alpha 0.8.0 is 20MB per world on Android, possibly the same for iOS. Since alpha 0.9.0, endless worlds are supported so i couldn't tell you that. If you want to see the total storage of the minecraft pe app, go to `Settings, Usage`, wait for it to load and then search for Minecraft. Also, if you want to know what app uses the most storage, it is sorted by usage so the app that uses the most storage is on the top.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft: Pocket Edition worlds can take up any amount of space on your device. This is becuase of the "Infinite" world type released in [alpha version 0.9.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#A0.9.0). The size of the world will increase as you explore.

You can check how much storage Minecraft is using by going to your device settings:

`Settings > General > Usage`

This menu displays the amount of space each app on your device uses, including Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

They can take up any amount of data due to the new infinite worlds. You can, however, turn this off when you create a world

Answer (score -3):

Minecraft isn't infinite, after passing 30 million blocks the game will crash. 
It'll use 20GB on your hard disk and its all uncompressed data.